# Dynamic Line between two points, click, move mouse, then click

Tags: java, mouselistener

I have to draw a Line in Java. I click one point, then release the mouse key, move the mouse (the end of the line should be where the mouse cursor is (a dynamic preview)) then click the mouse key again to make the line.

I see various questions on here, but most deal with holding a mouse button and dragging the mouse.

My question is, how can I draw a line dynamically using the method above. I am concerned about repainting. I had code earlier and it drew all the lines as I moved the mouse. Is there a way to just have a preview.

Comment: Have you tried to do it? Do you have sample code to propose? There are really too much missing for us to help you. What are you drawing on? Do you have other things being painted behind your "line preview"?

Comment: `..but most deal with holding a mouse button and dragging the mouse.` - so modify those examples for your purposes. The code would be very similar. The `mousePressed` would save the starting point. Instead of using mouseDragged you would use mouseMoved to drag the preview line. Then in mouseReleased you would save the end point. Of course you need a little extra logic to make sure you already have the starting point.

Answer (score 0):

You need need to create a application implementing both a `MouseEventListener` and a `MouseMotionListener`. Use the `MouseEventListener` method `mouseClicked` to check whether the mouse has been clicked and subsequently the `MouseMotionListener` method `MouseMoved` to update the other end of the line to your mouse's position. Finally you use the `MouseEventListener` again to pinpoint the end location of the line.

I hope this helps.

Take a look at:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mousemotionlistener.html.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of information missing in your post, so it will be difficult to offer an exact solution, but here is the general idea. Assuming that you need a transparent JComponent that receive mouse events and paint your line preview, the code would look something like this.

```
public class MyLinePreviewComponent extends JComponent {
    Point sourcePoint;
    Point destinationPoint;

    pubic MyLinePreviewComponent() {
        this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                if (sourcePoint == null)
                    sourcePoint = e.getPoint();
                else
                    sourcePoint = null;
                repaint();
            }
        });
        this.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                if (sourcePoint != null)
                    targetPoint = e.getPoint();
                repaint();
            }
        });
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        if (sourcePoint != null && destinationPoint != null) {
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.drawLine(sourcePoint.x, sourcePoint.y, destinationPoint.x, destinationPoint.y);
        }
    }
}
```

*Note that I did not run this code.*

If the line preview feature has to be added to an existing component, then you will have to repaint the regular content in paintComponent() *before* paiting the line.